# basic jquery slider animtype 'slide' not working

Tags: jquery

I am running the basic jquery slider

code

```
$('#slider').bjqs({
  animtype : 'fade',
  height : sliderHeight,
  width : sliderWidth,
  responsive : true,                      
  animduration : 450, // length of transition
  animspeed : sliderDelay, // delay between transitions
  automatic : sliderAutoPlay, // enable/disable automatic slide rotation

// control and marker configuration
  showcontrols : sliderShowNav, // enable/disable next + previous UI elements
  centercontrols : true, // vertically center controls
  nexttext : 'Next 1', // text/html inside next UI element
  prevtext : 'Prev 1', // text/html inside previous UI element
  showmarkers : false, // enable/disable individual slide UI markers
  centermarkers : true, // horizontally center markers

// interaction values
  keyboardnav : false, // enable/disable keyboard navigation
  hoverpause : true, // enable/disable pause slides on hover

// presentational options
  usecaptions : sliderShowText, // enable/disable captions using img title attribute
  randomstart : false // start from a random slide

});
```

As you can see I am passing in some of the values of the slider, for example the delay between slides.

The problem I am having is with the animtype. I cannot get the slider to work with it set to 'slide' even if I hard code it in.

If I change 'fade' to 'slide' the slider just loads the last image in and sits there doing nothing.

Has anybody else had a similar issue or can see where my code is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was I was sending the values in as strings.

changing the values to integers by wrapping in parseInt() fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

> the problem was I was sending **the values in** as strings..

Which values and were?

Comment: the values of height and width, if I added parseInt(); to them to convert to intergers, then all was good